# Search an object graph

Tags: .net, reflection

I thought I'd be able to do this much more simply than it's appearing to be.

I need the most efficient way possible to get all instances of a particular type in an object graph.

I have started using reflection to work my way through the object's properties looking for instances of this type and then continuing down all other complex types and collections. It is starting to feel like a lot of work as well as the sort of thing that someone must have had the need to do in the past. So before I commit myself to a load of work and testing I thought I'd ask if I'm missing a quick win within the framework or if there are any recommendations for libraries to do this kind of work.

Why do I want to do this?
I have a type that others are derived from. This type has common properties and more importantly a particular one identifying errors, HasErrors. This type is used in the building of models. Each model is different. Some simple and shallow some complex and deep. Each complex node would be a collection or a custom type deriving from this type, as a general rule. I need a quick way of traversing any instance of these checking all HasErrors property. Any instance of true indicates the model is in error.

```
Model  
    CustomerId (int)  
    CustomerDetails : MyType  
        Name (string)  
        DoB (DateTime)  
        Addresses (Collection<Address : MyType>)  
            [Line1 (string)  
             Line2 (string)]
```

Hopefully this kind of illustrates.

Comment: Is it your own type? Is it your own composite structure?

Comment: If you plan to be able to traverse an arbitrary graph of arbitrary types - you are right this is a load of work, (including avoiding circular references among other things). The real question here is how to re define, narrow down the task to make it simpler.

Comment: @Martin yes to both points. I have a base class method that needs to perform this function on the instance. It is the instance properties and thier properties that can be of the type I'm looking for.

Comment: @mfeingold As I started working on the issue I got the feeling it was no simple task. It feels like the kind of work a serializer would have to do, maybe something I could leverage the power of.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: @svick I've added some context to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to traverse the whole object graphs that consists of your types, you could make them all implement an interface like this:

```
interface IComponent
{
    IEnumerable<IComponent> Components { get; }
}
```

and then use this interface to walk the whole object graph. If the graph can contain cycles, you would have to guard against that, using something like a `HashSet<IComponent>` of visited vertices.

When implementing that interface, iterator blocks could be useful:

```
class FamilyMember : IComponent
{
    IEnumerable<IComponent> IComponent.Components
    {
        get
        {
            if (Father != null)
                yield return Father;

            if (Mother != null)
                yield return Mother;

            foreach (var child in Children)
                yield return child;
        }
    }
}
```

If you already have lots of types that are part of the object graph, doing this might be tedious. If that's the case and you don't mind the performance penalty, using reflection might be better for you.

Comment: Sorry it's been a while but I wanted to say thanks for the answer. I've taken a look and had a play in the real code and I can see what you are proposing. Unfortunately I do have a LOT of types. It may be that I use this or something similar when I have more time so I'm going to mark this as the answer. Cheers again.

Answer (score 0):

This is something of a "thinking outside the box" answer, but I don't think you should search *down* the tree, I think you should propagate errors *up* the tree.

Give every object either a reference to its parent, or to the root node of the model. When an object's `HasErrors` property becomes true, it sends a message up the tree to the root, either through all of its ancestors, or directly to the root, depending upon which kind of reference you've used.

This way, you know straight away when a model has errors, and you don't need to implement the complex, costly, and potentially fruitless top-down search of the tree.

Comment: This is similar to things I'd initially thought of. I'd have to go direct to the root as I wouldn't be applying my base class to all levels. Is a good suggestion though. Thanks for taking the time.